Transformations on Multiple Columns in Pandas Dataframe
Using the pandas framework in Python, I need to apply a transformation on 4 columns (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 in example Code) in a table.
The Transformation is quite simple:

Extract a Unix Timestamp
Convert Unix Timestamp to Datetime
Convert datetime to local timezone

Below is my current code, including the transformation:
data = [
    {"Col1": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col2": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col3": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col4": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col5": 1},
    {"Col1": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col2": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col3": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col4": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col5": 2},
    {"Col1": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col2": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col3": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col4": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col5": 3},
    {"Col1": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col2": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col3": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col4": "/Date(1591020000000)/", "Col5": 4}
    ]
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
   
 for col in ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']:
       df[col] = df[col].str.extract(r'\(([^\)]+)\)', expand=False)
       df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col],unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Australia/Sydney').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

As I am quite new to Python and Pandas, I would like to understand what is the most optimum method of achieving this?
It would seem that the current code is not really optimized as we are having to perform the transformation in 2 steps, iterating over all rows each time.
I have seen a lot of questions here where the apply method was used to iteratively process data in columns through either a private function or a lambda inline function.
After attempting this approach, I encountered many issues - mainly related to:

ambiguous data results
the lambda or private function failing due to NaN issues

The main questions:

How can inline column transformations be processed on multiple
columns using the apply method (ie. how can we replicate my code using the apply method)

What is the most optimal and efficient method of applying transformations to data in Pandas



read notice : [mre]

@PandaKim - just added the data and the original instantiation of the dataframe object - is this enough?

I would use a custom function to pass to apply, if you have issues with specific types of columns this could allow you to detect what is going on. Here is an example that would detect non-string columns and allow to ignore them (and show you a warning):
import warnings

def parse_date(col, tz='Australia/Sydney', out_fmt='%d/%m/%Y', errors='ignore'):
    try:
        return (pd
              .to_datetime(col.str.extract(r'\(([^\)]+)\)', expand=False)
                              .astype(float),
                           unit='ms')
              .dt.tz_localize('UTC')
              .dt.tz_convert(tz)
              .dt.strftime(out_fmt)
           )
    except AttributeError as e:
        if errors == 'raise':
            raise
        else:
            warnings.warn(f'Could not convert column "{col.name}" ({e})')
            return col

Then either apply your function to selected columns:
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(parse_date)

Or, since our function can ignore the offending columns automatically:
out = df.apply(parse_date)

Output:
         Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4  Col5
0  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020     1
1  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020     2
2  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020     3
3  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020     4

In the second case you would get a warning due to Col5:
UserWarning: Could not convert column "Col5" (Can only use .str accessor with string values!)


Code
With apply, it looks like this
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']
pat = r'(\d+)' # you can change pattern

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(
    lambda x: pd.to_datetime(
        x.str.extract(pat, expand=False).astype('float'),
        unit='ms',
        errors='coerce'
    ).dt.tz_localize('UTC')
     .dt.tz_convert('Australia/Sydney')
     .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
)

df
         Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4  Col5
0  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020     1
1  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020     2
2  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020     3
3  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020  02/06/2020     4

